# Is this use of "take to" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

Do the following sentences agree grammatically?

1. As per our religious teachings, we take to believe that God has created this universe.
2. Do I take to understand that global warming is a myth according to the study conducted by you?

Comment: Do I take it that global warming is a myth. Do I take  you to mean that global warming is a myth.

Comment: "Take to" is an idiom in English, but it does not have a meaning that makes sense in those examples. I can guess what they mean, but as they stand, they simply don't make sense.

Comment: You might consider "tend to" in place of "take to". [*tend to do something*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tend-to-do-something)

Answer (score 2):

1) Idiom: to take to **doing something**.

He stopped playing guitar and took to painting watercolors in the afternoons.

**To take to doing something** means to **start doing something**.

2) Idiom: **take [a person or this] to mean**

Do I take you to mean that global warming is a myth?

**To take someone to mean** means to understand that someone is saying some particular thing.

3) Idiom: **to understand someone to mean or say**
Do I understand you to mean that global warming is a myth? [same as 2)]

Summary: take to must be followed by the gerund (ing) and it means: to start something.

Another example: He took to believing in a better way of running the company and did everything to promote that.